# Cordova Ionic Keyboard pushes my div up - how do I fix it to the bottom of the screen, even with a keyboard present?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, animation

Recently I changed some transitions (changing two parent divs, respectively to "relative" and "absolute" respectively

I have a chat function for iOS and before this it was working fine, but since then, the chat input has jumped up about half the screen (the height of the keyboard).

Here's my code:

```
<div style="position: relative">
<div style="position: absolute">
    <div>
      <div id="messages-container" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 
      0px);">
        <div id="messages">
          <div class="message left">
            <span>Test from merchant</span>
          </div>
          <div class="message left">
            <span>Another test</span>
          </div>
        <div style="float: left; clear: both; height: 6rem;"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="msginput" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"> 
       <textarea placeholder="Message..." class="textareainput" 
       name="msginput" rows="1"></textarea>
        <div class="sendbutton">SEND</div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

Now, msginput is pretty normal I feel:


.msginput {
  border-top: 1px solid #d1d4d9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d4d9;
    z-index: 100;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    transition: transform 0.2s;  
}
```

Now obviously it's hard to demonstrate this as I can't generate a keyboard, but I hope that someone will have seen something similar in the past - it seems like it would probably be a common use-case. Note, without the keyboard, the fixed layout works perfectly fine, and without the top level divs for the animations it works fine.

What could be going on? I'm sure it's some setting in one of my divs.

I am able to calculate when the keyboard changes and move the input box accordingly, but this looks bad (even with animation), as it shifts to near the top of the screen

This is the library I am using:

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard

I am not using it with Ionic, and it doesn't need to be. I am doing this in a React app, but I don't think that's relative to this question.

Comment: You could try to set the **KeyboardResize** ([doc](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard#keyboardresize)) option to false?

Comment: Let me test it now

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to change anything. Still getting it flying to the top by the exact height of the keyboard.

Comment: I'm wondering if the fact that you don't use it with Ionic has any effect on the plugin behavior. Have you tried with Ionic? I guess not but could be worth a try to make sure the option works as expected with Ionic.

Comment: I have not as of yet tried it with Ionic. I may do so in the future, though that doesn't solve my issue here. I feel it must be a CSS issue

Comment: Indeed, you could work around it with some CSS but doesn't feel like a long-term solution though

Comment: That's the thing, I can't figure out the CSS to fix it. There seems to be absolutely no way of keeping it permanently attached to the bottom.